# Windows 8 simulator doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

The Windows 8 simulator which comes with Visual Studio 2012 does not launch either via debugging in Visual Studio or by running it directly.

As the simulator used remote desktop (RDP) and the issue occurs within Visual Studio & if I start it directly. I have identified that if my VPN is NOT enabled, then the simulator works fine. Thus I believe the issue is between VPN & RDP.

In the event log for RDP (`Application and service logs` - `Microsoft` - `Window`s - `TerminalServices-RDPClient`) I see the following message:

> RDP ClientActiveX has been disconnected (Reason= 5639)

Reason 5639 is `The policy does not support delegation of credentials to the target server.`

Are there any policies in group policy that I can change to enable delegation of credentials?

I have also tried turning off the firewall, setting RDP to all users and running the simulator as administrator but none of those options have helped.

Comment: Set the debugger to break on all thrown managed exceptions and see what shows up.

Comment: I did that, and unchecked "Enable just my code" in debugger options but nothing changes :( No exceptions have been thrown.

Comment: Does your VPN modify any Group Policy or do any kind of security hardening?

Comment: don't know for sure, probably. But I solved the problem and posting an aswer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Solution was to set the  checkbox `Automatically use my Windows logon name and password (and domain, if any)` in the VPN security properties, as shown below.

[image: Screen shot of the VPN properties dialog with the checkbox described in the answer highlighted]

Comment: Antonio, can you please, give more details on how to open this properties dialog and what version of the OS it is on?

Comment: it's x64 windows 8, go to VPN connection properties : Control Panel / Network and Sharing Center / Change adapter settings and then find your VPN connection, right click on it and select properties

Answer (score 6):

I got same issue, and it's also due to a VPN connection. As my computer is not on the office domain, I cannot check "Automatically use ..." option.

If you have same problem, you just have to disconnect from VPN on first simulator launch, then reconnect and continue to work!