# Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio Simulator + Wifi = Crashing

Tags: visual-studio, simulator, windows-8.1

The issue I am hitting affects both the Visual Studio 2012 & Visual Studio 2013 Windows Simulators since upgrading to Windows 8.1.

When I try launch it (in either in Visual Studio or externally by launching the exe) I get the following error message: `Client policy does not allow credential delegation to target server`

The odd part is that is only occurs on my work wireless and if if I disconnect the wireless, then it works fine. It does not occur on my home wireless.

I found a [similar issue with VPN's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881217/windows-8-simulator-doesnt-work) but I don't have any VPN's setup & the machine is not domain joined so I do not suspect an actual group policy.

Any ideas on what the cause for this could be?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few credentials that prevent the Windows Simulator from starting on Windows 8.1.  Run "control keymgr.dll" to open the windows credentials manager, then view the Windows Credentials.  If you have any of the following you will need to remove them:

"*",
"termsrv/*",
"localhost",
"termsrv/localhost",
"*session"

In the RTM build of VS 2013 there should be a more helpful error message in this scenario.

Comment: comment from future: as of VS 2015, the error message is indeed helpful.